# Getting 401 error while integrating eCommerce category or search api in android app

Tags: android, http-status-code-401

I am integrating woo commerce API in my android app.Api like http://demotwo.technitab.net/wp-json/wc/v2/products or /orders  are working fine.

But http://demotwo.technitab.net/wp-json/wc/v2/products?category=cat_id or search API are not giving data throwing 401 error.

I had tried my best but could not find any solution.

Any help will surely be appreciated..

Comment: **Error 401: Unauthorized**. Which means you do not have permissions or authority to access the url. Go through the API docs of the url whether the api requires some headers or some data like auth key to access the url.

Comment: Means server's url cannot accessible publicly or you have to attach AUTH (username&password) header with api to get access.

Comment: Sir i am attaching auth key like secret, consumer key(received from server), timestamp , noonce and signature with the base url. I am getting data in products or orders api but facing error only in http://demotwo.technitab.net/wp-json/wc/v2/products?search="search value"  and http://demotwo.technitab.net/wp-json/wc/v2/products?category="cat_id" api .. This i am unable to understand why error only with search and category api..

Comment: I had tried my best to solve the issue... Please reply as soon as possible ....

Answer (score 0):

finally i got the solution to the problem. I used "Scribe Library" available in android.